# Changing Auto Layout Anchor Constrains

Tags: swift, uitextfield, ios-autolayout

I have a `UITextField`, and I'm trying to change its position when the keyboard comes up. More specifically, I want to move the text field up so that it sits just above the keyboard. My code looks something like this

```
let textField = myCustomTextField()

override func viewDidLoad() {
     //set up textfield here
     //constrains blah blah

     textField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,
          constant: -view.bounds.height * 0.05).isActive = true

     //more constraints
}
```

What I want to do next is change that constraint so that it raises up the textfield when the keyboard comes up. My code looks like this:

```
 @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
     textField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,
          constant: -view.bounds.height * 0.05).constant = 200 //200 is a sample number I have a math calculation there
     textField.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

That doesn't work because referencing that constraint by just using `constraint(equalTo: constant:)` doesn't actually return any constraint. Is there any way to reference that constraint without creating a variable for each constraint I want to change and changing its constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you create a second constraint instead of changing the current , you should hold a reference to the created on and change it's constant , you can reference it like this

```
var bottomCon:NSLayoutConstraint?

override func viewDidLoad() {

   bottomCon =  textField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,
      constant: -view.bounds.height * 0.05)
   bottomCon.isActive = true

 }
```

then you can access it in any method and play with constant property

Edit: for every constraint you create assign identifier and access it as below

```
 let textFieldCons= button.constraints.filter { $0.identifier == "id" }
 if let botCons = textField.first {
      // process here
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to store that variable somewhere that's not in my view controller? Like within whatever view I'm applying those constraints to? Because say I want to change 20 constraints, would I have to store all of those as separate variables in the view controller?

Comment: I'm not using storyboard to set the constraints, so I'm trying to set the identifier programmatically, but nothing I do works. I'm trying to set the constraint identifier by doing constrain.identifier = "some identifier", but when I iterate through the items, constraints, none of them have any identifiers. Can you only add identifiers through storyboard?