# Layout Anchors in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, layout-anchor

I am endeavoring to update / streamline my code pertaining to Auto Layout vs NSConstraints, however it seems to be baffling me for now.

I have some Swift 3 code which slides in a UIView on the tap of a button, however the UIView is controlled with NSconstraints and works fine. -

```
@IBAction func rightFlyOutButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if (rightFlyOutShowing) {
            if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad {
                leftFlyOutLeadingConstraint.constant = 25
            } else {
                leftFlyOutLeadingConstraint.constant = 15
            }
            rightFlyOutTrailingConstraint.constant = rightFlyOut.frame.width * 0.93
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {self.view.layoutIfNeeded()})
        } else {
            if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad {
                rightFlyOutTrailingConstraint.constant = 25
            } else {
                rightFlyOutTrailingConstraint.constant = 15
            }
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {self.view.layoutIfNeeded()})
        }
        rightFlyOutShowing = !rightFlyOutShowing
    }
```

Trying to use AutoLayout and Layout Anchors, I cam up with this -

```
@IBAction func rightFlyOutButton(_ sender: Any) {
        rightFlyOut.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        rightFlyOut.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.93).isActive = true
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {self.view.layoutIfNeeded()})
    }
```

This returns a multitude of errors -

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6000000949b0 h=-&& v=-&& FasteM.UIViewX:0x7fed7140c600.width == 0.500741*UIView:0x7fed7161d760.width + 150.222   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000000900e0 FasteM.UIViewX:0x7fed7140c600.width == 0.93*UIView:0x7fed7161d760.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000095a90 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x7fed7161d760.width == 375   (active)>"
)
```

My logic is I am anchoring the right edge of the view to the superview and specifying the width of the actual view (i.e. 93% of the superview.

I'm sure this is a simple error that i'm missing, but I would appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

TIA

Comment: Adding to Sh_Khan's answer, which is good advice, it looks like you also have autoresizing masks on the view you are animating. Typically with autolayout, you don't use the autoresizing masks, (think `translatesAutoresizingMasksIntoConstraints = false`). If you want the autoresizing masks, then ignore this comment, but if you don't want them or don't know what they are, I would suggest turning them off. It may not fix your animations exactly how you want, but it will get rid of some odd constraints in the console that you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

the problem with the second approach is that for every click it will create other constraints which will make a conflict with the old same ones , so you should create those constraints any where , get a reference to them and change their constants as you did in first right approach

Comment: This answers seems to the point. It is a shame that it has been downvoted without a reason.

Comment: @Sh_Khan, thanks for your reply. Are you suggesting I keep with the NSConstraints version (Swift 3) or simply I must specify original Anchors prior to changing the constants (Swift 4)?

Comment: yes, specify original anchors and have a reference to them by declaring NSLayoutConstraint vars  before changing constants in the button action , look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49117408/changing-auto-layout-anchor-constrains/49117452#49117452

Answer (score 0):

I've had a bash around with this problem and finally came up with a working solution -

Firstly create a variable :

```
var LeftFlyOutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
```

Then use the following code in viewDidLoad() :

```
leftFlyOut.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false    
LeftFlyOutConstraint = leftFlyOut.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 35)
    LeftFlyOutConstraint?.isActive = true
```

And finally the button :

```
@IBAction func leftFlyOutButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if (leftFlyOutShowing) {
            LeftFlyOutConstraint?.isActive = false
                LeftFlyOutConstraint = leftFlyOut.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -40)
            LeftFlyOutConstraint?.isActive = true
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {self.view.layoutIfNeeded()})
        } else {
            LeftFlyOutConstraint?.isActive = false
            LeftFlyOutConstraint = leftFlyOut.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 35)
            LeftFlyOutConstraint?.isActive = true
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {self.view.layoutIfNeeded()})
        }
        leftFlyOutShowing = !leftFlyOutShowing
    }
```

And no reported errors.